# How to insert path at the end of line number 3

Tags: text-processing, sed

Consider the file shown below whose name is `DRC.txt`.
The contents of the file are:

```
#############Actions#################
set a [project $p get_action ICV_DRC]
action $a set_parameter "ruledeck"
action $a set_parameter "options"
```

Now I have one variable called `ruledeck = /praj/test/drc_tsn/test1`. I need to append the value of this variable which is the path at the end of third line in the DRC.txt. I was trying to do it using `sed`, but the path is not added only the variable is. How can I solve the above problem?

```
sed -i -e '3s/$/"$ruledeck"/' DRC.txt
```

This command gives output as shown below:

```
#############Actions#################
set a [project $p get_action ICV_DRC]
action $a set_parameter "ruledeck" $ruledeck
action $a set_parameter "options"
```

I want output like this instead:

```
#############Actions#################
set a [project $p get_action ICV_DRC]
action $a set_parameter "ruledeck" /praj/test/drc_tsn/test1
action $a set_parameter "options"
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues here. First, your `sed` command is in single quotes (`''`), so the variable isn't expanded:

```
$ echo $ruledeck 
/praj/test/drc_tsn/test1
$ echo '$ruledeck'
$ruledeck
```

I see you've put the variable in double quotes within the `sed` command, but that won't change anything since the entire thing is single quoted. You need to double quote it instead:

```
sed -e "3s/$/$ruledeck/" file
```

However, that will also break:

```
$ sed -e "3s/$/$ruledeck/" file
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown option to `s'
```

This is because your variable contains `/`, but you are also using `/` as the delimiter for the substitution operator (`s///`). You need a different delimiter. This should do what you want:

```
$ sed -e "3s|$|$ruledeck|" file
#############Actions#################
set a [project $p get_action ICV_DRC]
action $a set_parameter "ruledeck"/praj/test/drc_tsn/test1
action $a set_parameter "options"
```

But that still isn't quite right if the line doesn't have a space in the end. To also add the space, but only if it isn't there already, use `\?` ( a space and an escaped question mark) to match "0 or 1 space". Putting all this together gives:

```
$ sed -e "3s| \?$| $ruledeck|" file
#############Actions#################
set a [project $p get_action ICV_DRC]
action $a set_parameter "ruledeck" /praj/test/drc_tsn/test1
action $a set_parameter "options"
```

Comment: The Last command which you mentioned is not giving the desire result which I want.

Comment: @Lalitkumar I can't help if you don't tell me what's wrong! It works exactly as I show on the example file you gave us. Is the value of `$ruledeck` as I show?

Comment: My guess: OP expects the `-i` flag and the filename `DRC.txt`...

Comment: The value of $ruledeck which is the path is not appended at the end of 3rd in DRC.txt file by using this command- sed -e "3s| \?$| $ruledeck|" DRC.txt

Comment: @Lalitkumar but does it print the right output? Note that I'm not using `-i`, so the file won't be changed.

Comment: @terdon I had use -i flag also but still the path is not appended in the DRC.txt file.

Comment: @Lalitkumar I don't know why that would happen, there's nothing strange in the command. Are you sure that `$ruledeck` is set correctly? What does `echo "$ruledeck"` print?

Comment: @terdon you are needlessly adding the `\?` regex construct when you are already specifying a space on the RHS of the s/// command. `"3s|\$| $ruledeck|"` would suffice.

Comment: Plus, the shell variable `$ruledeck` needs to be escaped for it to be safely used in the RHS of an s/// command. What if it contained the very delimiter you are using, viz., | ? Or the ampersand.

Comment: @RakeshSharma I use that only for the case where there is already a space so as not to add two. And there is no need to escape, I know the contents of the variable, that's the point. In any case, I can't escape it. If you need to escape, you would have to do that before passing it to sed.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid any issues with quoting and regexp delimiters by using `ed` to append a line after line 3, and then join line 3 and the new line 4.  e.g.

```
printf "%s\n" 3a " $ruledeck" . 3,4j  wq | ed -s DRC.txt
```

`printf "%s\n"` is used to pipe each of its remaining arguments to the text-editor `ed`, one at a time.

`ex` or `vi -e` (or `vim -e` or `vim -E`) could be used instead of `ed` - but note that `ex` and the various implementations of `vi` insert a space when joining lines, while `ed` does not (so the space at the beginning of the quoted string `" $ruledeck"` is not needed with those).   They, along with `sed` and other related programs, all implement the same basic editing commands, with some mostly-minor differences, which originated with [qed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QED_(text_editor)) in 1965.  Some also implement significant extensions to those commands.